# how can I make range with text and make this to y-axis in plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two questions!

Q1.
first I want to make a list like

```
df.CellNo = [Cell1,Cell2,Cell3,...,Cell96]
```

so I tried `df.CellNo = ['CellNo'] + range(1,97)` but it was not working.

so I did a code like behind.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CellNo': range(1,97)})
df.CellNo = df.CellNo.astype(str)
df.CellNo = 'Cell' + df.CellNo
```

Is there any easier way to do this?? (in short way)

Q2.
second I want to plot with x-axis is 'Time' data and y-axis is df.CellNo data
when I just plot df

[image: two muppets]
I want to make y-axis sorted by nuber
like Cell5, Cell6, Cell7, Cell10, Cell11 ... from behind.
how can I do,,

Comment: Comments are  [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196977/discussion-on-question-by-seoyoung-how-can-i-make-range-with-text-and-make-this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this is about sorting dataframe by substring.

You can make a key column and then sort the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time' : [20190721,20190722,20190723], 'No':['A90','A5','A10']})
df['key'] = df['No'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
df.sort_values('key', inplace=True)
plt.scatter(df.Time,df.No)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Cooool!! You save my life. May I ask one more question??  If I convert df.Time values to string (df.Time.astype(str)) it doesn't work again. graph's x-axis goes [2.00, 3.00, 1.00] is there other way to solve this??

Comment: @seoyoung It was `int` and thus `plt.scatter` **reordered** based on natural order. When you changed it, it no longer holds any hierarchical meaning, and used as given. Try using `plt.scatter(sorted(df.Time.astype(str)),df.No)`.